# Problems with Deserialization and XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm using Visual Studio 2010(c#) and I am having some issues with my XML deserialization code.  I can't get it to read my XML properly.

My XML reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<command_strings version="1">
  <commands>
    <command cmd_id="1" state_id="1" label="On" cmd_type="fixed" cmd_string="1%0D" />
    <command cmd_id="1" state_id="3" label="Off" cmd_type="fixed" cmd_string="0%0d" />
  </commands>
</command_strings>
```

My code looks like:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Command
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("cmd_id")]
    public int cmd_id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("state_id")]
    public int state_id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("cmd_type")]
    public string cmd_type { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("cmd_string")]
    public string cmd_string { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("commands")]
public class CommandCollection
{
    [XmlArray("commands")]
    [XmlArrayItem("command", typeof(Command))]
    public Command[] Command { get; set; }
}

public void XMLStrings(string myXML)
{
    CommandCollection commandscollection = null;
    XmlSerializer dserial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommandCollection));

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\123.xml");
    commandscollection = (CommandCollection)dserial.Deserialize(streamReader);
    streamReader.Close();
}
```

Any idea what I may be missing?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you share how this is not working properly?

Comment: For some reason i am not able to get the XML attribute values from the XML file.

Comment: Yes, miss that when passing over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommandCollection` class should be marked with the attribute `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("command_strings")]`.
You should also add a property for `version` and mark it with a `XmlAttribute` attribute.